# What is a reliable way to get output from instantiated processes in c++?

Tags: c++, centos7, c++17

Basically what I want to do is to instantiate a program in a Linux shell and get the outputs that it emits to stdout into a string or list of strings (per line, depending). The program I want to run in my c++ application is just a `ps aux`.

- All the "solutions" I've found didn't completely solved my problem. Most of them fell under the error described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25857954/2414842). Basically `popen` fails and doesn't return the complete output from the shell execution. Let's call this "error 1" for the sake of this question.

What I've tried so far:

1) Using boost, I tried this following their [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html#boost_process.tutorial.io):

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
namespace bp = boost::process;
bool is_process_running(std::string p_name){
    string cmd = "ps aux";
    bp::ipstream out;
    std::string line;
    bp::child c(cmd, bp::std_out > out);

    // the while is supposed to read each line of the output
    // but the execution doesn't even enter the while
    while(c.running() && std::getline(out, line) && !line.empty())
    {
        if(line.find(p_name) != std::string::npos)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    c.wait();
    return false;
}
```

2) I also tried:

```
bool is_process_running(std::string p_name){
    string cmd = "ps aux";
    std::array<char, 256> buffer;
    std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe(popen(cmd.c_str(), "r"), pclose);
    if (!pipe) throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    while (!feof(pipe.get())) {
        if (fgets(buffer.data(), 256, pipe.get()) != nullptr)
        {
            // here the line comes incomplete
            std::string line(buffer.data());
            if(line.find(p_name) != std::string::npos)
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But this last one also fell into "error 1".

3) [This code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10702464/2414842) fell into the "error 1"
4) [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20617844/2414842) also fell into "error 1"

I don't this it is necessary to put the codes for 3) and 4) because it is literally what is in these answers, I didn't change anything, but if you guys need I can edit my question. So my question is just this, how to get the command output in a way that will work? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:
I've tried with the code snipped provided:

```
bool is_process_running(std::string p_name)
    FILE* p = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
    if (!p) { cerr << "oops"; return 2; }
    char line[500];
    while (fgets(line, 500, p))
    {
        std::string linha(line);
        if(linha.find(p_name) != std::string::npos)
            return true;
    }
    fclose(p);
    return false;
}
```

In this case, here is an example of the truncated output from popen/fgets:

```
[fabio ~]$ ps aux | grep 391
root       391  0.0  0.1  48580 12864 ?        Ss   Sep03   0:06 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
fabio 15435  0.0  0.0 112548   960 pts/2    S+   15:40   0:00 grep --color=auto 391
```

The line for the process 391 is as this one but at runtime it only returns me `"root       391  0.0  0.1  48580 12856 ?        Ss   Sep03   0:06 /usr/lib/system\n"`

Comment: In a nutshell: Launch your process (plain `fork`/`exec*`). Connect a `pipe` from the `stdout` of the new process to your process. `read` data from the pipe when available and store it in some container/buffer in your process. When the child process terminates, parse the data in your container (the output from the child).  That's *one*, fairly simple, way of doing it.

Comment: No. I'm not going to write up an example for you that you should be able to easily find online yourself based on the keywords given - this is fairly basic stuff with lots of material covering it online, if you do a bit of research. SO is not a free code writing service (nor am I).

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a055ba0ca0d8043 what truncated output do you mean? Please show your code, its expected output, and its actual (truncated) output.

Comment: For code snippet 1) you state `"execution doesn't even enter the while"`.  Why not?  Have you run it under a debugger?  Note that the code shown in 1) is not quite the same as for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187867/how-to-run-a-process-and-get-its-output-using-c-libboost) -- in that question you also had shell redirection `2>&1` which could cause problems.  The code shown in 1) here works exactly as expected for me.

Comment: @G.M. yes I've debugged it and that's how I acknowledge that it is not entering the while loop, now if you ask me why, I don't know. Indeed I removed the `2>&1` to see if the problem stops. You are not the first one who told me that my examples works for you, the only thing I may conclude this is that either my system or my libs are broken or too outdated because this all makes no sense

Comment: You should explain *why* you run `ps aux` and what processes do you really care about. For example, if you are searching some process, you should explain that (and what are you searching for). I see no gain in running `ps aux` programmatically

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't think this is the scope of the question but since you insist: I need to know if some processes are running given both its name and arguments. I can't know this using `pidof` or `pregp` because these don't consider the arguments passed. For the same reason I can't grep inside `proc` folder, running `find /proc | grep my_process` and returned zero results

Comment: But why can't you code (without creating any process) some functions accessing `/proc/` directly (as mentioned in my answer)?

Comment: @Fabiotk: next time you ask some question, please *motivate it* and *give some context* in the question itself, not in some comments for it. Do you understand that the initial form of your question was some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the relevant system calls *directly*: [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html), [close(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html). Read some good Linux programming book (perhaps the old [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) which has several chapters related to your question). Look for inspiration into the source code of other free software programs dealing with pipes (e.g. of some simple shell like `sash`) and/or into your `libc` (or [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/), it has very readable code) for the code of `popen`.

We don't have the space and time to explain in details, but you'll find many resources on the Web, and ALP is freely downloadable; of course `execve` is the last system call that usually runs in the child process, since it is re-initializing the virtual address space.

To read from the pipe without limiting the line length. Either use [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) manually (and care about the buffering), or consider [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) (see also f[dopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fdopen.3.html))

You might be interested by frameworks like [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.io/).

You probably want to avoid [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) (and you don't need something using `/bin/sh`, unless your command needs to be expanded for [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)); see [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)).

Be aware of [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) (and perhaps [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) ...)

---

> The program I want to run in my c++ application is just a `ps aux`

Then you probably should [not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/939778/841108) run any external process, but instead **access `/proc/` *directly*** (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html); you'll need [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) etc...) or perhaps thru some `libproc`. Of course `ps aux` is accessing `/proc/` itself (so you don't gain anything except some simplicity by running `ps`, and you lose some performance and some robustness by using it). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50397466/841108), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48346065/841108), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47194864/841108), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47110393/841108), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48089620/841108) answers.

In a comment you mention

> I need to know if some processes are running given both its name and arguments.

That is a good case for accessing `/proc/` programmatically: loop on `/proc/` directory with `opendir`, looping `readdir`, `enddir`. For each entry given by `readdir` check that it has a numerical name (starting with a digit) otherwise skip it. With that numerical name (for example `1234`) construct a path like `/proc/1234/cmdline` and [open it then parse its content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12237783/841108) (it has separating <kbd>NUL</kbd> bytes). This is probably not harder than starting a `ps aux` process, getting and parsing its output, and is certainly more efficient. (To understand details, run `od -cx /proc/self/cmdline` then `od -cx /proc/$(pidof systemd-journald)/cmdline` and understand its output).

Comment: The problem with scanning the /proc directory is that it changes while you read it.

Comment: the examples are not clear in how to write into the pipe the outputs from `execve` since execve will halt and only return if an error happens

Comment: But `ps aux` is scanning `/proc` and it is also changing while `ps` runs

Comment: @Fabiotk: take several hours or days to read more. That matter is very well explained.

Comment: I see it, the fact that it has separating null bytes kind makes things harder since passing to `strcmp`, `strstr` only compares until the end of the string (ie, the null byte). But thanks for the help, now the problem is easy to solve

Comment: No, that should make things *easier*. You just fill a buffer with all the content of `/proc/1234/cmdline` (e.g. looping till `fread` fails), and you can use pointers *inside* that buffer (and pass such internal pointers to `strcmp`)